# Android Image to Bitmap for use in Google Vision Barcode api

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera2, google-vision

I need to convert `android.media.Image` to a `BitMap` so that I can use it in the [Google Vision Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview). I've tried the following...

```
    byte[] imageData = new byte[image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().remaining()];
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
    System.out.println(barcodes.valueAt(0));
```

... but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference.
```

Google's example code references so the deprecated `Camera` API but I am using `camera2` which is why I cannot use them for help.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to make sure `imageReader` was in `JPEG` format instead of `YUV`

```
 mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 3);
```